# trouble with normal distribution

Tags: python, plot, gaussian

I have code to plot a gaussian distribution but it is not centered on 0 as it should be:

```
def gaussn(x):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-0.5*x**2)

X=np.linspace(-5,5)
GAUS=gaussn(X)
plt.plot(GAUS)
```

Why it is centered on 25 and not 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try plt.plot(X,GAUS) instead.  By not specifying the x-axis, it's just running from 0 to 50 (i.e., the length of the array).